# Hosting for Angular 2, mongoose, gulp and node

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose, gulp

I develop an application in Angular 2, mongoose, gulp and node.
What hosting service could you use?
What are the steps to mount an application of this type on a hosting server?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using [Webpack](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) for handling hosting.

With Webpack it is easy to setup different environments (dev, prod) with many configuration options. It provides a development server and many options to prepare your app for hosting. It supports tree-shaking (dramatically reduces the size of your application) and manages all the loading of your assets.

Hosting depends on your country. You can theoretically use any provider. Angular2 apps do not require any special configuration / plugins  / services.

The steps are quite easy: Build your app, configure Webpack according to the guide found in the link above or [here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/)(Very nice description of how to build your application for production in an efficient way), and then start the production build via npm as described.

After that you could just drag your application to your ftp server and link the index.html. That's it!

Comment: Webpack is a bundler.

Comment: Yes but he is asking for the steps to host an Angular2 application. And I told him that the host depends on the country he lives in. Any host with webspace will theoretically do it!